# Pass Image from Map Annotation to Details View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, image, viewcontroller, mkannotation

I have class with the name Capital in the separate swift file. In my (ViewController) I declare location, image, title and etc for each of the pins on the map. When pin is tapped calloutAccessoryControlTapped pops up and it directs me to my DetailsViewController, where I passed the title of the tapped pin, but I can't pass an image...

```
    let Headquarters = Capital(title: "Headquarters", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (some latitude), longitude: (some longitude) ), info: "Our headquarters", image: "Location1")
```

And then I have my perfectly working segue from ViewController to DetailViewController

```
      override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {

        let theDestination:DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController 
        theDestination.toPass = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.title! } }
```

My Class Capital

```
    import MapKit
    import UIKit

class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var info: String
var image: String?


init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String, image: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.info = info
    self.image = image
}
 }
```

And that's how I have it in the ViewController(declaring them)

```
    let Headquarters = Capital(title: "Headquarters", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (some coordinate), longitude: (some coordinate)), info: "Our headquarters", image: "Location1")
```

And there are several more of them

```
    mapView.addAnnotations([Headquarters, BlahBlah, OtherStuff])
```

Then I put them into pins

```
      func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Capital"

    if annotation.isKindOfClass(Capital.self) {

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {

            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "pin")


            let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        } else {

            annotationView!.annotation = annotation

        }

        let cpa = annotation as! Capital
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.image!)

        return annotationView

    }


    return nil
}
```

And then I'm trying to pass image to DetailsViewController

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are passing the image in your `prepareForSegue`, did you load it in your detailViewController ?
First I would declare a variable in the detailVC :

```
var image: UIImage?
```

and then I would pass the image in your ViewController :

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {

        let theDestination:DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController 
        theDestination.toPass = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.title! 
        theDestination.image = UIImage(named :"your-image-name")
    } 
}
```

And then in the `viewDidLoad` of the detailVC I would set my variable image to my IBOutlet ImageView :

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    self.imageView.image = self.image
}
```

Comment: The thing is that my image names (for each of multiple pins) is inside of my MKAnnotation, and I don't want to pass it as a (named: "") with the string. How can I pass that?

Comment: Can you post your code where you store your image inside your MKAnnotation ?

Comment: So if in your `prepareForSegue` you try to do this :
`theDestination.image = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.image!` 
it's not working ?

Comment: Also : 
You may be able to pass directly the image,
`annotationView!.image = cpa.image!`

Comment: theDestination.image = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.image!  tells me that value of type 'MKAnnotation' has no member 'image'